# Append contains more rows than constituent tables

Tags: sas, sas-dis

I've got 4 tables (in SAS DIS 4.9) with the following numbers of rows respectively:

```
A - 38 rows
B - 13 rows
C - 4575 rows
D - 22 601 rows
```

Each table has the same set of columns with the same formats, as follows:

```
TIME
ID
FIRST_NAME
LAST_NAME
LOCATION
```

I append the tables, and the output of this append has 34 207 rows. I'm trying to understand how this could happen (notice that there are 6980 extra rows here).

I could do some joins to try to investigate which rows were created, but there are two issues here: first, if I don't understand how appends of this software work there's a good chance I don't understand how the joins work, and second another issue (which may be related) is that it is taking forever for me to run the transformations and open the output tables.

Is there some special property of appends of which I am unaware, perhaps a box I should have checked?

Much gratitude for your time.

Comment: Please post the generated code.  Many of us here are not super familiar with DI Studio, but are experts in the SAS code it generates.

Comment: @Rookatu, can you please let us know the transformation you used for appending tables. Also, can you please let us know if rerunning job is increasing the record count of target table or the count remains same after rerunning the job flow.